# с помощью string ,надо через cin написать название функций, чтобы оно заработало в созданной функцией Showinfo!! (не могу написать правильно код ))

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;


string DataFromBD()
{
    return "Data From BD";
}

string DataFromWEBSER()
{
    return "Data From WEBSER";
}

void ShowInfo(string str)
{
    cout << str << endl;
}

void main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    ShowInfo(a());// надо правильно написать здесь!
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите (что значит - правильно заработало? Правильно - это как?), но скобки при строке (`a()`) в вызове функции явно лишние... Изложите внятно исходную задачу, что нужно? Просто вывести строку? `ShowInfo(a);` Непонятно только к чему у вас все эти предыдущие функции... Да, на всякий случай - `cin>>a` читает **одно слово**, а не строку.

Comment: я хочу подключить функций сверху такие как DatafromBD или DataFromWEBSER с помощью cin и string если это возможно кнч) во вот сюда ShowInfo(a) но незнаю как это сделать

Comment: Не к автору вопроса - люди, если кто-то понимает, что хочет автор, поясните... К автору у меня после "незнаю" и "кнч" вопросов больше нет...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ваша строка не может указывать на функцию. Можно сделать например так:

```
std::unordered_map < string, string(*)()> call{
{"DataFromBD", DataFromBD},
{"DataFromWEBSER", DataFromWEBSER}
};
string a;
cin >> a;
ShowInfo(call[a]());
```

или

```
string(*F)() = DataFromBD;
string a;
cin >> a;
if (a == "DataFromWEBSER")
    F = DataFromWEBSER;
ShowInfo(F());
```

По разному, только нужно как нибудь указывать на функцию.